# Sequelize n:m join table 1:m eager loading relationship

Tags: sequelize.js

There is an example in the sequelize docs as follows (I have a similar usecase).

```
 ItemTag = sequelize.define('item_tag', {
  tag_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    unique: 'item_tag_taggable'
  },
  taggable: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: 'item_tag_taggable'
  },
  taggable_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    unique: 'item_tag_taggable',
    references: null
  }
});
Tag = sequelize.define('tag', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
});

Post.belongsToMany(Tag, {
  through: {
    model: ItemTag,
    unique: false,
    scope: {
      taggable: 'post'
    }
  },
  foreignKey: 'taggable_id',
  constraints: false
});
Tag.belongsToMany(Post, {
  through: {
    model: ItemTag,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: 'tag_id'
});
```

Now, lets say I have to include one additional relationship and table:

```
ItemTagReaction = sequelize.define('item_tag_reaction', {
  reaction_type: {
     type: Sequelize.ENUM.apply(Sequelize, reactionTypes),
  },
  tagResponse: Sequelize.STRING(256),
});
```

Now, I include an additional relationship here:

```
ItemTag.hasMany(ItemTagReaction);
```

How can I eagerload the ItemTagReaction when querying for Post?

```
Post.findById(2, {
  include: [Tag],
})
```

The ^^ above works, but I do not know how to make sure ItemTagReaction is also loaded.  If you include it you get an error that it is not related to Post.  If you try and nest include it to Tag, you get an error that they are also not related.

Help!?

Answer (score 0):

In your definition, Post is related to Tag. But neither Post nor Tag are associated with ItemTagReaction and ItemTag.

You must associate ItemTagReaction to either Post or Tag. Then you can either include it (Post) or nest include it (Tag).